# interesting IP's?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

I had seen a very interesting IP (something like 1.0.0.4) that was of some root DNS server and responded to pings, but I can't remember the exact IP. Anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 - Google DNS.

4.2.2.2 (actually .1-.6) - Verizon (ex-Bell Atlantic, ex-GTE) DNS.

Answer (score 0):

list of IP's for root servers is [here](http://www.root-servers.org/)

Can't see anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

The whole of 1.0.0.0/8 (along with 2.0.0.0/8) is reserved for future used by IANA (for when they run out of IPv4 addresses basically), so it won't of been that.

You might be thinking of the recent Google public DNS launch, they used 8.8.8.8 and 4.3.2.1 and respond to IP addresses, but the IP's wont relate to a single server so the responses will fluctuate.

Comment: Google also uses 8.8.4.4. I don't think they've publicly announced 4.3.2.1, so I wouldn't depend on it.